# Android how to access files from internal memory?

Tags: java, android

I have a method for sending string files to server. Now I need to access .txt files from android Bluetooth folder and convert them into Strings. Could anyone possibly help me on this?

Comment: I think there should be some acronym **WHYT** for the famous and all-time repeated question "What Have You Tried"?

Comment: you can access storage by using URI, just use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Bluetooth folder you should try below methods. Put the methods in a `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`. So here it:

```
public List<File> folderSearchBT(File src, String folder)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] filesAndDirs = src.listFiles();
    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);
    for (File file : filesDirs) {
        result.add(file); // always add, even if directory
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            List<File> deeperList = folderSearchBT(file, folder);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is a recursive method which will add all folders in the src parameter into a List.

```
public String searchForBluetoothFolder() {

    String splitchar = "/";
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    List<File> btFolder = null;
    String bt = "bluetooth";
    try {
        btFolder = folderSearchBT(root, bt);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("FILE: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < btFolder.size(); i++) {

        String g = btFolder.get(i).toString();

        String[] subf = g.split(splitchar);

        String s = subf[subf.length - 1].toUpperCase();

        boolean equals = s.equalsIgnoreCase(bt);

        if (equals)
            return g;
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this method: [getExternalFilesDir(String type).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) And use [`DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) as type.

If you add "bluetooth" to the end you'll get the bluetooth download directory.

Then access the file

Comment: as he mentioned, He want to access only android Bluetooth folder